# Evento jquery al entrar a input?

Tags: jquery

Tengo un input con la clase albaran y quiero que al entrar en el input se dispare eeste evento, pero no he logrado.

```
$('.albaran').on('focus', function () {
   console.log($(this).data('error'));
});
```

Comment: Aquí funciona https://jsfiddle.net/ebnk8jea/ tendrás tu código HTML para ver si no te falta jalar jQuery o agregar `$(document).ready`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dado que tu elemento es creado dinámicamente, el listener del evento se debe de implementar a todo el documento, de tal forma que como un parámetro más sea la clase de tu elemento:

```js
$input = $("<input class='albaran' type='text' data-error='Error'/>");
$('body').append($input);

$(document).on('focus', '.albaran', function () {
   console.log($(this).data('error'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si el elemento no es creado de forma dinamica, te recomiendo usar la funcion `.focus()`

En terminos simples tu codigo seria:

```
$('.albaran').focus(function () {
   console.log($(this).data('error'));
});
```

Si tienes alguna duda, comenta.

Suerte.

**Actualizacion**

En ese caso lo unico que debes hacer es cambiar las comillas simples por dobles, se que suena tonto, pero tenia un problema similar pero con "click"

```
$('.albaran').on("focus", function () {
   console.log($(this).data('error'));
});
```

Si tienes una duda comenta, Suerte.

Comment: el elemento es creado de forma dinamica

Comment: actualice la respuesta, espero que te sirva

Answer (score 0):

debes de cambiar tu codigo por lo siguiente

```
$('.albaran').on('focusin', function () {
   console.log($(this).data('error'));
});
```

......

El metodo de eventos de JQuery focusin se presenta solo cuando se le hace focus a dicho input o elemento del DOM y a raiz de ese evento generar una reaccion.

Puedes saber mas al respecto desde el siguiente link. https://api.jquery.com/focusin/ la cual es la pagina oficial de JQuery

Comment: ¿No podrías explicar **por qué** esto es la (psoible) solución?

Answer (score 0):

Debería funcionar.

Aquí tienes el ejemplo funcionando:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.albaran').on('focus', function() {
    console.log($(this).data('error'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="albaran" data-error="mensaje de error">
```

Comment: Asier, te comento a ti porque veo que tienes bastantes puntos más que los de los demás usuarios que han respondido. Creo que este tipo de preguntas, en las cuales todo funciona, se deberían de dejar como comentario y cerrar la pregunta por "no ser reproducible" ya que no aporta nada a lectores que lleguen a esta pregunta en un futuro, si no hay un motivo que sea el causante del error.

Comment: Sí, en parte tienes razón. Pero mostrarle al que pregunta que esa parte del código funciona también puede ayudar a que descarte posibles problemas y hacerle buscar en la dirección correcta para solucionar el error. Incluso al lector que pueda llegar buscando información sobre el tema le pueda aportar encontrar ejemplos de código funcionando. No sé. No lo tengo tan claro.

Answer (score 0):

Aquí te agrego otro ejemplo.

```js
var input = document.querySelector('input'),
    log = document.querySelector('.log');
multipleEventsListeners(input, 'keyup change', function(e){
  log.textContent = 'Valor agregado: ' + this.value;
});



function multipleEventsListeners(elem, events, func) {
  var event = events.split(' ');
  for (var i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
    elem.addEventListener(event[i], func, false);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  
  <input type="number" value="1" />
  <p class="log"></p>

</body>
</html>
```